# Filtering pandas Dataframe on Parent Child Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe df having 3 columns.

```
    _id  parent_id  type
    A    B          Subcategory_level
    B    null       Main_Level
    D    A          Product_Level
    M    N          Product_Level
    X    Y          Subcategory_Level
    Z    X          Subcategory_Level
    L    Z          Product_Level
```

What I want as my output is :

```
    _id  parent_id  type
    D    A          product_level
    M    N          product_level
    L    X          product_level
```

What I tried is , Drop all of the rows having type equals main_level. Then

```
    df1=df
    df1.rename(columns= {'_id':'parent_id','parent_id':'_id'}, 
 index=str,inplace=True)
```

Then Natural join of df1 with df:

```
    final_df=pd.merge(df,df1,on='parent_id', how='inner')
```

But the problem in this natural join is, if there are more than one level of type , it will not work. e.g The relation between X and L have 2 level of hierarchy, in that case it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you're saying?

```
df[df.type == 'product_level']

_id  parent_id  type
D    A          product_level
M    N          product_level
L    X          product_level

# Maybe I don't understand what you mean. I thought it was. 

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3,4], "b":["x","t","s","g"], "x":["l1", "l3", "l1", "l2"]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   a  b   x
0  1  x  l1
1  2  t  l3
2  3  s  l1
3  4  g  l2

In [4]: df[df.x=="l1"]
Out[4]:
   a  b   x
0  1  x  l1
2  3  s  l1
```

Comment: How u get L,X product_level in output??

Comment: Dont know who have upvoted this answer ,But your output is wrong

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean.